# Passing information to other CCScene's in Cocos2D-X?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

How can I pass information in? Right now, there's a static constructor method called "create" but it's created from CCScene. How can I pass in my own arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another static method with whatever arguments you want in your Layer which returns Scene object.

Here is pseudo code :

```
CCScene* MyLayer::scene(bool arg0)
{   
    CCScene * scene = NULL;
    do 
    {
        scene = CCScene::create();
        MyLayer* pLayer = MyLayer::create();
        scene->addChild(pLayer);
    } while (0);
    return scene;
}
```